# Como alterar a posição do gráfico na figura no matplotlib

Tags: gráfico, matplotlib

O gráfico ficou pequeno e mau posicionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
for i in df.index:
    plt.plot(df.at[i,'x0'], df.at[i,'y0'], label=i)
    
# A e B
plt.axvline(x=ABx, ymin=0.1, ymax=0.55, linestyle = "dashed", color='gray')
plt.scatter(ABx,ABy, marker= 'o', color='black', s=20, alpha = 0.8)
plt.annotate('Ponto Crítico da Produção A e B (' + str(ABx) + ', ' + str(ABy) + ')', (ABx,ABy),
            textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
            xytext=(20,0), # distance from text to points (x,y)
            ha='left' # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
            )

# B e C
plt.axvline(x=BCx, ymin=0.1, ymax=0.4, linestyle = "dashed", color='gray')
plt.scatter(BCx,BCy, marker= 'o', color='black', s=20, alpha = 0.8)
plt.annotate('Ponto Crítico da Produção B e C (' + str(BCx) + ', ' + str(BCy) + ')', (BCx,BCy),
            textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
            xytext=(20,0), # distance from text to points (x,y)
            ha='left' # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
            )

x0, y0, r = 0, 0, ABx                    # dados do círculo
t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)          # dominio da função (passo 0.01 para melhorar a precisão)
x = x0 + r * np.cos(t)                   # calculando X e Y
y = y0 + r * np.sin(t)
plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', linestyle = "dashed")

x0, y0, r = 0, 0, BCx                    # dados do círculo
t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)          # dominio da função (passo 0.01 para melhorar a precisão)
x = x0 + r * np.cos(t)                   # calculando X e Y
y = y0 + r * np.sin(t)
plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', color='green', linestyle = "dashed")

plt.title('Von Thunen') 
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('LUCRO LÍQUIDO')
plt.xlabel('DISTÂNCIA')
plt.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, linestyle = "solid", color='black')
plt.axhline(y=0, xmin=0.4, xmax=1, linestyle = "solid", color='black')

#plt.box(False)
plt.axis('equal')
#plt.axis([0, 40, 0, 70]) # [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ajudaria ter uma porção ou a totalidade do dataset para conseguir replicar exatamente

Comment: Verdade, falha minha. O notebook está aqui: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xRPYWWXjlq0DhQ1zRckhXrk0lGxAr0pI?usp=sharing e o csv com os dados aqui: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GGbVw11izHDpqUfPZD64BERGianb0w37/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Lamento mas o csv que partilhaste não contém as colunas que o código acessa, ex: `x0`. Para te ajudar melhor teria de replicar exatamente o gráfico e o problema que tens.

Comment: Não percebi, mas se essa parte estiver no código coloca esse trecho também na pergunta

Comment: Desculpa, eu devia ter facilitado desde o inicio, achei que compartilhando o notebook seria mais fácil. Eu acrescento duas colunas X0 e Y0 ao Data Frame assim:     `df['y0'] = list(zip(df.LB, df.CT*0))
df['x0'] = list(zip(df.LB*0, df.LB/df.CT))`

Comment: Coloca `plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))` antes do ciclo for e vê se resolve o problema sff.

Comment: O tamanho ficou excelente, mas o gráfico fica centrado na origem (0,0) e eu queria deslocar todo ele para a esquerda porque tem muito espaço vazio à esquerda.

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução. Plotei um ponto à direita do gráfico, em (60,0), fazendo o centro do gráfico não mais coincidir com a origem. Não é a coisa mais elegante do mundo mas o resultado ficou infinitamente melhor.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]